# BEM best practise - crossing blocks

Tags: css, bem

I ask myself what is BEM best practise if you have two blocks which are crossing the markup. I like to share my question with you here. In the following two solutions a like to give an example:

Solution A)

```
<div  class="flexblock" >
    <div class="flexblock__cellelement dateblock">
        ...
        1.1.2020
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Solution B)

```
<div  class="flexblock" >
    <div class="flexblock__cellelement">
        <div class="dateblock>
          ...
          1.1.2020
          ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is Solution A) permitted in the way of the BEM concept (http://getbem.com/) ? Maybe there is another and better solution.

Comment: these are not the same. first one is using one div and you can style just one div. for example just one background-color. but second is two div and you can style two.

Answer (score 0):

As @Elyas said, given examples are not the same thing. I will try to explain both.

**A)** This "technique" should be used to "alter" a property or position for the element according to the parent. Here is a better example:

```
.avatar {position: static;} 
.header__avatar {position: absolute; top: 0;}
.footer__avatar {position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
```

In general the Avatar has static position, but in different parents can have specific position.

More info in docs: https://en.bem.info/methodology/css/#external-geometry-and-positioning

In your example if `.flexblock__cellelement` and `.dateblock` should point or be treated as one element the markup should be:

```
<div  class="flexblock" >
    <div class="dateblock flexblock__dateblock">
        ...
        1.1.2020
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

**B)** `.dateblock` is just a "child" of the **E**lement `.flexblock__cellelement`. While `.flexblock__cellelement` can contain multiple elements it is not a good idea to have selector like `.flexblock__cellelement .dateblock` (of course some little exceptions can be made in certain situations).